# why don't find spotipy.oauth2 module in spotipy?

Tags: python, spotipy

I have install spotipy and have try the example but there is a problem. Here is the code :

```
import spotipy
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials


birdy_uri = 'spotify:artist:2WX2uTcsvV5OnS0inACecP'
spotify = spotipy.Spotify(client_credentials_manager=SpotifyClientCredentials())

results = spotify.artist_albums(birdy_uri, album_type='album')
albums = results['items']
while results['next']:
    results = spotify.next(results)
    albums.extend(results['items'])

for album in albums:
    print(album['name'])
```

The following exception is raised:

```
from spotipy.oauth2 import SpotifyClientCredentials
ImportError: No module named oauth2
```

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Is one of your scripts named `spotipy`? If you do, rename it.

Comment: yes dude! now work! thanks

Comment: Awesome, posting it as an answer :)

Answer (score 3):

If one of your scripts is called 'spotipy', rename it to something else. Otherwise Python tries to look for 'oauth2' in your script.

Comment: Damn it! once in a while I fall into this bad naming convention trap.
Also OP please mark this as an answer, new comers might go without checking this out.